# Traverse nodes in XML

Tags: xml, ant, xml-parsing, svnant

I need to traverse the nodes of an xml file in another xml file. So i have just loaded the second file into my current XML file and i need to run a loop around this file to find nodes with a certain tag. How do i do this in XML?

```
<loadfile
      property="changed.files"
      srcFile="log.xml">
</loadfile>
```

Loaded my file this way now i tried to use ant-contrib task which has a for loop but i need to run it on diff machines and ant-contrib is not a task that comes by default with ant so i need to add that into the ant configuration as well so this is not ideal. Any suggestions how i traverse nodes in XML?

Answer (score 0):

Ant doesn't have great facilities built-in for traversing XML.  You'd probably do well to grab the excellent [XMLTASK Library](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) and include the jar for it in something like a /tools directory in your project.